# Use an array in Laravel update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I would like to push an array in **Where Clause** of Laravel Update Query.

Here is the update query.

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->update(array('votes' => 1));
```

Is it possible to use the query like below ??

```
$array_of_ids;
DB::table('users')->where($array_of_ids)->update(array('votes' => 1));
```

Thanks

Comment: use `whereIn` to update

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use `whereIn`:

```
$array_of_ids;
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $array_of_ids)->update(array('votes' => 1));
```

Please read the documentation carefully. In this case, all kinds of `where` statements are documented here: [Query Builder - Selects](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter. But this query updates another field also which contain datetime data.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty certain this query should work. What exactly gets updated?

Comment: query is working but it also updates another field containing datatime data.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might have set up the database field so it sets the current time when inserting/updating automatically...

Answer (score 4):

Try this query:

```
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $array_of_ids)->update(['votes' => 1]);
```

Using Model:

```
User::whereIn('id', $array_of_ids)->update(['votes' => 1]);
```

Comment: This one works. Great

Answer (score 0):

using the query builder: The query builder can also update existing records using the update method. The update method, like the insert method, accepts an array of column and value pairs containing the columns to be updated. You may constrain the  update query using where clauses:

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('id', 1)
        ->update(['votes' => 1]);
```